# Как правильно делать копию эталонного объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо при посещении новой области игроком создавать случайный ландшафт. На данный момент пытаюсь решить задачу так: на карте присутствует скрытый объект ландшафта, от которого делается клон, которому уже присваивается случайная карта высот:

```
public class ChunkLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Terrain flat;

    void Start()
    {
        Terrain terrain = Instantiate(flat, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        HMapGenerator(terrain);
    }

    Terrain HMapGenerator(Terrain terrain)
    {
        // ... //
        terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
        return terrain;
    }
}
```

Однако, сколько я не искал, так и не обнаружил свойства или метода, с помощью которой клон можно отобразить на карте. Либо я в принципе неправильно решаю задачу, либо что-то упустил.

Comment: Вы его уже отобразили, если у префаба есть `Mesh Renderer`, то он после создания будет отрисовываться. Вопрос в том, что вы все копии префаба спавните в одной начальной точке `(0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в том-то и дело, что не отобразил. Если я в редакторе ставлю галочку Basic Terrain -> Draw - он появляется, по-умолчанию она не стоит, так как снята у эталона.А где они рисуются я и так знаю: мне пока надо саму отрисовку сделать, а там уже можно и к камере её привязать.

Comment: А почему на эталоне не стоит галка? Поставить ее вручную в коде можно через GetComponent.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker потому что мне не нужно, чтобы он вообще отображался на карте, только клоны.

Comment: Префаб хранится на диске, как он у вас может отображаться на карте?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker тогда вопрос, как делать префаб, сохранённый на диске, потому что пока единственное, что я придумал - это просто скрытый объект на карте.

Comment: Тогда это не префаб, а обычный объект, читайте, что такое префабы.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а в вопросе он где-то назван префабом?

Comment: Да, на код свой посмотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом примере было сразу две ошибки.

Первая - нет никакой причины оставлять объект на сцене. После создания и настройки эталона достаточно было создать в проекте папку Assets/Prefabs и перетащить в неё эталон их иерархического древа сцены. После этого объект со сцены можно удалить, а эталон брать по необходимости, из файлов проекта.

Вторая - создавая копию объекта следует помнить, что она обладает всеми свойствами эталона, в том числе и ссылками на другие компоненты, которые вы **не копировали**. В данном конкретном случае объект `Terrain` связан с тем же компонентом `TerrainData`, что и префаб, и эти данные сохраняются на диске отдельным файлом. В результате, эта строчка:

```
terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
```

изменяет **общую** карту высот копии и оригинала, что сводит на нет всю затею.

Решением проблемы является создание нового объекта класса `TerrainData`:

```
TerrainData tdata = new TerrainData();
```

изменение его так, как вам нужно, а затем уже создание из него игрового объекта `Terrain`:

```
GameObject terrobj = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(tdata);
```

Затем создайте создайте пустой игровой объект на вашей сцене и присоедините к нему свой скрипт.